# How do I start defining map from fold?

Tags: scheme, racket, higher-order-functions, fold, htdp

I'm working through Htdp 2e, and have been given the problem of defining the map function from foldr or foldl. I'm not sure where to start.

Map takes in a function of one argument and a list. So I have defined my
function similarly. Fold requires a function of two arguments, a base, and a list.

My issue is how do I take the one argument function of map and recreate it  with a two argument function in fold?

The purpose of the problem is to teach how to create abstractions using higher order functions.

Some push in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

```
; [X Y] [X -> Y] [List-of-X] -> [List-of-Y]
; consumes a function and a list and applies f 
; to each item in the list

(define (map-from-fold f l)
    (foldr f base lx))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think about the main difference between `foldr` and `map`:

```
(map add1 '(1 2 3))  
; == (cons (add1 1) (cons (add1 2) (cons (add1 3) '())))

(fold f '() '(1 2 3) 
; ==> (f 1 (f 2 (f 3 '())))
```

Notice that `f` needs to `cons` as well as whatever function is added. Thus when you pass `f` to `map` the function that is passed to `foldr` needs to both `cons` the result of `(f element)` with the accumulator. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to get the result I wanted. It took a bit of thinking but finally with some trial and error came up with a result. Thanks for the help!